# SSRS 2008 -- Data Missing when run in BIDS mode

Tags: sql, reporting-services, bids

I am having a really weird issue with a report built in SSRS 2008. When the report is set to export as a PDF, all data fields are showing up properly on each page as intended. However when the report is run in BIDS mode or exported to Word/CSV/Excel formats there are several data fields that show up as a blank.

One weird thing Ive noticed is that if I set the data fields that are missing as First(Fields!datafield.value) instead of Fields!Datafield.value then they will show up.

Has anyone ever seen any instances of this happening or have any ideas how to correct this issue without redoing the report? I can include the .rdl file if that would help.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SSRS are you developing for?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar when coloring fonts. The pdf export didn't pick up all the formatting. Check to make sure that your visibility and color settings for the fields in question are what you expect. Try setting those all to default to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I will try this today and let you know how it goes although the report is only in black and white -- I know, I know... 1950's called, they want their color scheme back ;)